# Linked List push back

Tags: c++, linked-list

please take a look at my push back and insertBefore in my linked list class.

```
template<class T>
void LinkedList<T>::push_back(T item) {
    Node<T> *n = new Node<T>;
    if(head == nullptr)
    {
        addFirstNode(item);
    }
    else
    {
        n->data = item;
        n->next = nullptr;
        n->previous = tail;
        tail = n;
    }
}

template<class T>
void LinkedList<T>::insertBefore(T item, T key) {
    if(head == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "List is empty" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    Node<T> *temp = head;
    while(temp->next != nullptr)
    {

        if(temp->next->data == key)
        {
            Node<T> *n = new Node<T>;
            n->data = item;
            n->next = temp->next;
            temp->next->previous = n;
            n->previous = temp;
            temp->next = n;

            //if n is the first node
            if(n->previous == nullptr)
            {
                head = n;
            }

             return;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    std::cout << key << " is not on the list.";
}
```

the push back only works in my test once.
the insertBefore does not work at all.
I already tried to draw out my list, but I still don't know what I get wrong.

Comment: Please show us how you're testing your linked list.

Comment: Please show a [mre] and give us some more details of _how_ it is not working.

Comment: for your push_back, add tail->next = n; before tail = n;

Comment: @che.wang Please don't answer in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to practice your drawing.

This is what your `push_back` does with a one-element list:

```
      +---+---+
head—>|nul|nul|
      +---+---+
        ^
        |
       tail


----------


Node<T> *n = new Node<T>;

      +---+---+     +---+---+
head—>|nul|nul|     |   |   |
      +---+---+     +---+---+
        ^             ^
        |             |
       tail           n


----------

n->next = nullptr;

      +---+---+     +---+---+
head—>|nul|nul|     |   |nul|
      +---+---+     +---+---+
        ^             ^
        |             |
       tail           n


----------


n->previous = tail;


      +---+---+     +---+---+
head—>|nul|nul|<-----   |nul|
      +---+---+     +---+---+
        ^             ^
        |             |
       tail           n



----------


tail = n;

                     tail
                      |
                      v
      +---+---+     +---+---+
head—>|nul|nul|<-----   |nul|
      +---+---+     +---+---+
                      ^
                      |
                      n
```

As you can see, the first node still has a null "next" pointer.
I'm pretty sure that you can fix that bug – you're missing one step.
(Work it out with drawings *before* writing the code.)

Drawing the other function left as an exercise.